# Retrofitting "alert()" on delete buttons

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular application which contains several delete buttons somewhat like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="delete($index)">x</button>
```

Now as we are nearing production deployment and I want delete buttons to behave nicely and "alert()" the user before actually deleting the object.

How can I retro-fit this feature in all the delete buttons through a directive. I would like to have a directive called "ask":

```
<button ask class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="delete($index)">x</button>
```

which I can use to affect the behaviour of any button.

Somehow I am not able to think through this

```
app.directive("ask", function() {
  return function(scope, elems, attrs) {
    // what to do here:
    // 1. shall I change the elems.attr("ng-click")
    // 2. or scope.attrs("ngClick")
    ????
  }
});
```

Please guide me with the best practice and some code samples. Also note that the ng-click callback of all the delete buttons are different and the application already makes extensive use of isolate scope and child scope directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this implementation

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .directive('ask', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {ask: '@', onAsk: '&'},
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.on('click', function(e) {
          if(confirm(attrs.ask)) {
            scope.onAsk();
            scope.$apply();
          }
        });
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('ItemsCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5];
    $scope["delete"] = function(index) {
      $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
     };
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="ItemsCtrl">
  <ul><li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">{{item}}
  <button ask="Are you sure you want to delete item?" on-ask="delete($index)">x</button>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This approach is nice, it helps me to preserve the styling of those buttons as well. Why is "$apply" necessary here? Even after writing around 15K lines of angular code I am not conceptually clear on this.

Comment: Because I used here a native event listener (`on('click', ...`) without executing scope.$apply angular doesn't that you want update a view after you modified an array. So scope.$apply will run the digest cycle and after splicing an element will update your list. If you checked - without it an array modified but the view doesn't rerender

Answer (score 1):

You can build a `directive` for this and in `template` of `directive` have `button` element and the `ng-click` event.

Pass `index` and `delete` function as inputs to this directive.

```
app.directive("deleteFruit", function(){
  return{
    // You can also pass one more binding if you want to have a specific alert message
    scope:{
      index: '@', delete:'&'
    },
    template:'<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="deleteFruit()">x</button>',
    link: function(scope){
      scope.deleteFruit = function(){
        // When user clicks, first call the alert function then use the promise returned by dialog and check whether user wants to delete or not
        //modal.dialog().then(function(userSelectedOption){
            // If user wants to delete then go a head and call delete function on main controller
        //  if(userSelectedOption){
        //    scope.delete(scope.index);
        //  }
        //})
        scope.delete(scope.index);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

*MainCtrl* HTML

```
 <delete-fruit delete="delete(index)" index={{$index}}></delete-fruit>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jSyZduhp9ILhbbILOm2z?p=preview).

Comment: Nice one, only one minor downside is that, all my buttons are styled differently. But your solution can be slightly modified on the lines of @Gudz to overcome this.

Comment: You can also pass styles as well right and use `ng-style`, `ng-class` etc..